# What's the best way to find out the user name in a bash script/command?

Tags: bash

So far I've used something like this in scripts, aliases and in the shell:

```
qstat -u $USER
```

Now I found out that neither the `$USER` variable nor `$USERNAME` is not a built-in in bash. While `$UID` and `$EUID` are.

I could of course use `$(whoami)` or stuff like that. There are thounds of ways to find out the user name of the current process. But what's the best, most protable and short one of them and why?

Comment: [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) requires `$LOGNAME` to be set, but mentions that `$USER` is also used.  Don't base security decisions on the value of `$LOGNAME` or `$USER` because I can do `USER=root` and `LOGNAME=root` even if I'm logged in as `pleb`.

Answer (score 6):

[whoami](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/whoami/) looks deprecated. What about the suggestion of `id -un`?

> The whoami utility has been obsoleted by the id(1) utility, and is equivalent to ``id -un'.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, `$LOGNAME` is defined with the name of the current user.